# Как перейти на новую активити но что бы DrawerLayout работал и там?

Tags: java, android, listview, drawerlayout

В `DrawerLayout` есть `ListView`(с меню), по клику по любому пункту я передаю в поток запрос и ответ кидаю в `ListView2`(под меню допустим), расположенный в `MainActivity`.Дальше уже с `ListView2` тоже кликаю по подменю, и погружаю данные. Дальше я передавал в новый активити данные, и там выводил их но есть проблема: в новом активити `DrawerLayout` недоступен!

Вопрос: может я неправильно делаю, но мне надо что бы `DrawerLayout` был всегда доступен в каждой активити. Наверно неправильно делаю и не надо новое активити создавать. Наверно можно как то `MainACtivity` динамически менять `ListView2` на другой элемент?

Comment: Я порекомендовал бы использовать фрагменты

Comment: имеете ввиду в маинактиви создать два фрагмента и один скрывать когда надо а друго показывать и наоборот?

Comment: Вам нужно либо добавить `DrawerLayout` во второй `Actvitiy`, либо использовать фрагменты. Фрагменты использовать будет **правильно**

Comment: фрагменты (( я даже не знаю что это такое и с чем его едят..
Получается что у меня будет три фрагмента 
"Под меню"--->"Еще данные" ---->"данные конкретно одной записи"

Comment: У разработчика нет такого оборота речи - "не знаю что это такое" .. есть [документация (операция по тексту есть активити)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/fragments.html), открыл - почитал - использовал. Что недопонял - нагуглил.

Comment: Ну если в первый раз такое пишешь то такие вопросы это нормально ..

Comment: фрагменты это фрагменты. Можно создать фрагмент размером с экран. В таком случае активити будет выступать в качестве контейнера, а экраны будут реализованы на фраментах. Советую использовать Support библиотеку - и обратная совместимость дальше и работает без багов (в свое время в не support столкнулся с багом который так и не смог обойти, пришлось все переводить на support)

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понял, что вы имели ввиду без исходного кода, но почему бы не использовать первый `ListView` из `DrawerLayout` для загрузки данных.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?